# calling a service inside a controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm working with ng-resource to do CRUD manipulations as following :

```
app
.factory('candidatureService',['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:8080/candidature/candidats', {}, {
      update: { method: "PUT"}
    });

  }]);
```

I only need PUT in my case.

and in the controller I have this :

```
app
  .controller('CandidatureStartCtrl', function ($scope, candidatureService) {


    $scope.candidature = {};
    $scope.candidature.guarantor = {};

    $scope.submitForm1 = function(isValid) {
      console.log('validate form');

      // check to make sure the form is completely valid
      if (isValid) {
        console.log('form 1 is amazing');
        console.log($scope.user);
        candidatureService.update({},{
          "username": "Uchiha",
          "nom": $scope.candidature.lastname,
          "prenom": $scope.candidature.firstname,
          "nomarab": $scope.candidature.arabicLastname,
          "prenomarab": $scope.candidature.arabicFirstname,
          "genre": $scope.candidature.gender,
          "dateNaissance": $scope.candidature.birthdate,
          "email": $scope.candidature.email,
          "telephone": $scope.candidature.phoneNumber,
          "photo": $scope.candidature.photo,
          "cin": $scope.candidature.identityDocumentCode,
          "adresse": $scope.candidature.address,
          "codeMassar": $scope.candidature.codeMassar,
          "lieuNaissance": $scope.candidature.placeOfBirth,
          "cinPhoto": $scope.candidature.identityDocument,
          "anneebac": $scope.candidature.anneebac,
          "nomGarant": $scope.candidature.guarantor.fullName,
          "lienGarant": $scope.candidature.guarantor.link,
          "telephoneGarant": $scope.candidature.guarantor.phoneNumber,
          "province": {
            "codeProvince" : $scope.candidature.province
          }
        });
        $scope.steps.step2=true;
      } else {
        console.log('form is invalid');
      }

    };

  });
```

`username` is the primary key in my case.

but when I use this controller I'm getting this error message :

```
TypeError: candidatureService.update is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/app/scripts/controllers/candidature-start.js:106:24)
```

in my index.html I've declared the controller and the service as following :

```
<script src="scripts/controllers/candidature-start.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/service/candidatureService.js"></script>
```

and when I access to my page I call the `'CandidatureStartCtrl'` which is declared in `candidature-start.js` :

```
.state('candidature.start', {
        url: '/start',
        controller : 'CandidatureStartCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/tmpl/frontend/candidature-start.html',
        containerClass: 'hz-menu',
        resolve: {
          plugins: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load([
              'scripts/vendor/slider/bootstrap-slider.js',
              'scripts/vendor/touchspin/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.js',
              'scripts/vendor/touchspin/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.css',
              'scripts/vendor/filestyle/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js'
            ]);
          }]
        }
      })
```

So why I'm getting that error message it took me 3 hours but I couldn't figure out whats the problem !

Comment: try  `return candidatureService.update({},{
          "username": "Uchiha",
          "nom": $scope.candidature.lastname,
          "prenom": $scope.candidature.firstname,
          "nomarab": $scope.candidature.arabic....`

Comment: make sure you included your service in `app.module`

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad as you can see I have0 `app.` before my factory so it's already included

Answer (score 0):

Method names in your services get prepended with a $ when you use $resource, so the call should be to candidatureService.$update